# Match two lists, one with partial strings and another with full string, return the whole string if match

Tags: regex, r, string, match, substr

Match two lists in R, one with partial strings and another with full string, return the whole string if matches. Return only the unique matches (once).

So, let's say I have a CSV file and each row has a long string (the long list). Then, I shorten the string using substr, and then I drop any duplicate strings using unique. Then I want to compare the long string list `df12` with the unique short list `df14`, and if there are unique matches on partial string search (`df14` vs `df12`),  then return the whole string from `df12`.

This is `df12` (long string list)

```
    [1] I like stackoverflow very much today
    [2] I like stackoverflow much today
    [3] I dont like stackoverflow very much today
    [4] I dont like you!
    [5] What? 

df13<-substr(df12, start=0, stop=30)
```

This is `df13` (shortened strings - not unique)

```
[1] I like stacko
[2] I like stacko
[3] I dont like s
[4] I dont like y
[5] What? 
df14<-unique(df13)
```

This is `df14` (shortened strings - unique strings after applying unique method)

```
    [1] I like stacko
    [2] I dont like s
    [3] I dont like y
    [4] What?
```

This is the result that I want in the end

```
    [1] I like stackoverflow very much today
    [2] I dont like stackoverflow very much today
    [3] I dont like you!
    [4] What?
```

Comment: `df13<-substr(df12, start=0, stop=30)` doesn't produce the expected output for me. Should it be `df13<-substr(df12, start=0, stop=13)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach to match every short string in df14 with all possible matches in df12 and output them, including the short string as an index into the list to know which one matched the ones in df12:

```
df1 <- c('I like stackoverflow very much today', 'I like stackoverflow much today',
         'I dont like stackoverflow very much today', 'I dont like you!',
         'What?')
df2 <- c('I like stacko',  'I dont like s', 'I dont like y', 'What?')

sapply(df2, function(x) df1[grepl(x, df1)])
$`I like stacko`
[1] "I like stackoverflow very much today" "I like stackoverflow much today"     

$`I dont like s`
[1] "I dont like stackoverflow very much today"

$`I dont like y`
[1] "I dont like you!"

$`What?`
[1] "What?"
```

Comment: I get an error that was saying `" invalid regular expression, reason 'Missing ')"`... Then in your very elegant solution added `"sapply(df2, function(x) df1[grepl(x, df1, fixed=TRUE)])"` I am wondering, is there a way to get the longest one of the matches, if multiple matches exist for one Unique string to the short string list?

Comment: You can take the output of the above `sapply` command, save it to something called `l` lets say, and you can run this command to get the longest matching long string for each short string: `lapply(l, function(x) x[nchar(x) == max(nchar(x))])`

Comment: Thank you @user3949008 ! This was very helpful!